# How to put data from variable into TeXViewDocument (flutter_tex)

Tags: flutter, dart

It's easy to declare a raw string

```
var tempString = r'<span class="math-tex">\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)</span>';
```

But how can I convert an existing string to a raw string?

```
var tempString = '<span class="math-tex">\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)</span>';
String temp = r'${tempString}';
```